# HTML ID issues when adding new elements to the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, post

Hi all I have a form in which I dynamically add in a new row consisting of a text box and check button on button press. However I need some sort of way to know which checkbuttons were pressed in the post data and therefore need a value field consisting of an ID on each of the the check buttons, code is seen below:

```
<div id='1'>
    <div class="template">
        <div>
            <label class="right inline">Response:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="responseText[]" value="" maxlength="400" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" name="responseRadio[]" value="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" name="addNewRow" value="Add Row" />
    </div>
</div>
```

JS to add new row:

```
var $template = $('.template');
$('input[type=button]').click(function() {
    $template.clone().insertAfter($template);
});
```

can anyone suggest a good way to help me know in the post data which text field, links to which check button, and to know if it was pressed?

Comment: give some name and id to the textbox & checkbox while adding it/??

Comment: ^how would I do this in JS ? im sorry I am totally new JS and therefore If I give the first textbox and checkbutton a name it will just clone every time a new row is added

Comment: then use `$this` to get the clicked button prperties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add `id` to each of your newly created radio button and textbox, do:

```
var i=2;
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('html').on('click','input[type=button]',function() {
        //clone the last create .template div
        //so that when we insert, it gets added at the end
        var $template = $('.template:last');
        $clone = $template.clone(); 
        //find input with name responseText[] and add id text2 to it
        $clone.find("input[name='responseRadio[]']").attr('id','text'+i);
        //find input with name responseText[] and add id radio2 to it
        $clone.find("input[name='responseRadio[]']").attr('id','radio'+i);
        //insert the cloned element (at the end)
        $clone.insertAfter($template);
        //keep the counter incremented for the next element
        i++;
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DDuY9/)**

Answer (score 1):

You could use the $('input[type=button]').val() to get the value attribute of your clicked button. Or you can use the $('input[type=button]').attr("name") to get the attribute name of your button.

To see if a radio button is checked use: $('#test').attr('checked');
In this case you need to give an id 'test' to your chekbox.

For example:

```
var $template = $('.template');
$('input[type=button]').click(function() {
var name = $('input[type=button]').attr("name"); //Will return addNewRow
$('#test').attr('checked'); //Will return true or false for the radio/chekbox with the id test

$template.clone().insertAfter($template);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

call a jquery function before submitting the form, which removes 'name' attributes of the radio buttons which are not checked, and then creates a hidden element with attributes `name="responseRadio[]"` and `value="false"`

```
$('form').submit( function(e) {
    $('.template').each( function() {
        var radio = $(this).find('input[type="radio"]');
        if( !radio.is(':checked') ) {
            radio.attr('name', false);
            radio.after( '<input type="hidden" name="responseRadio[]" value="false" />' );
        }
    });
});
```

The above code will include all text inputs and respective radio inputs in correct order. unchecked radios will have value `"false"`